# Bogo Plugin: Post in alternative language appears on blog despite draft, scheduled or bin status

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the [Bogo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bogo/) plugin on a [OnePress](https://www.famethemes.com/themes/onepress/) theme to create Polish versions of my English posts. When I create drafts or scheduled posts in English, everything is fine. When I create the translated versions of these posts in Polish, no matter what status I set (draft, scheduled, move to bin!) they appear immediately on the Polish blog index. To hide them, I have to delete them and permanently empty the bin.

My theme:

- OnePress 1.2.4 (also tested with 1.3.0 with the same result)

My active plugins:

- Bogo 2.8.1 (also tested 3.1 with the same result)
- CBX Flexible CountDown 1.7.2
- Contact Form 7 4.5
- Justified Gallery 1.1
- Limit Login Attempts 1.7.1
- Password Protected 2.0.3
- Postman SMTP 1.7.2
- Windows Azure Storage for WordPress 3.0.1
- Wordpress Branding 1.0.3
- WP-Optimize 2.0.1

Comment: have you check , confliction of plugins.

Comment: As far as I could yes, I checked.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see in the Bogo plugin code, it looks like in some instances it retrieves posts without consideration for status.

Similar issue:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/draft-post-is-unintentionally-linked/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I somehow missed this support topic. Too bad the plugin author haven't yet fixed it.